How to annotate type of Manager().from_queryset()?
In Django I have custom QuerySet and Manager:
from django.db import models

class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def live(self):
        return self.filter(is_draft=False)

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def publish(self, instance: "MyModel"):
        instance.is_draft = False
        instance.save()

In my model I want to use both, so I use from_queryset method:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects: CustomManager = CustomManager().from_queryset(CustomQuerySet)()

    is_draft = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)

Since I annotated objects as CustomManager, Pylance (via vscode) logically yells at me that MyModel.objects.live() is wrong, due to Cannot access attribute "live" for class "CustomManager" Attribute "live" is unknown.
Removing type annotation leads to similiar complaint: Cannot access attribute "live" for class "BaseManager[MyModel]" Attribute "live" is unknown.
How to annotate objects in MyModel so Pylance will be aware that objects also has CustomQuerySet methods available, not only CustomManager methods?

Looking at Django's source from_queryset constructs a new subclass of CustomManager by iterating through CustomQuerySet methods:
@classmethod
def from_queryset(cls, queryset_class, class_name=None):
    if class_name is None:
        class_name = "%sFrom%s" % (cls.__name__, queryset_class.__name__)
    return type(
        class_name,
        (cls,),
        {
            "_queryset_class": queryset_class,
            **cls._get_queryset_methods(queryset_class),
        },
    )

So as @chepner pointed out in his comment we get a structural subtype of CustomManager, whose _queryset_class attribute is CustomQuerySet. So the question fundamentally is: how to type annotate that dynamically generated subclass in a way at least good enough for type-checker and autocomplete to work?
Approaches that I looked at so far are unsatisficatory:

Django doesn't type annotate return of from_queryset.
Django-types annotates it as type[Self], which lacks CustomQuerySet methods.
Same with Django-stubs.


Is there some sort of inheritance relationship between CustomQuerySet and CustomManager?  Without one, I don't see how a single object (objects) can simultaneously have two different types.

@PaulCornelius from_queryset method subclasses CustomManager with methods from CustomQuerySet, see docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset

So what type does objects have at runtime? Statically (and logically), it seems to be some intersection of CustomQuerySet and CustomManager, but Python does not currently support static intersection types (e.g., CustomQuerySet & CustomManager).

@chepner sadly django doesn't provide return type for this method, by default it is infered as sadly lacking type[CustomManager]. Looking at django source is quite interesting in this case: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d4b2e06a67c2e1458305c3eac6c4b2b3e917daf9/django/db/models/manager.py#L108

Ugh, it generates a new class dynamically to return. You don't know the nominal subtype of CustomManager it will return, but you do know the structural subtype it will return: it will be a type whose _queryset_class attribute is CustomQuerySet. You might be able to define a custom Protocol to use as the type hint.

@chepner never used Protocol before, I am reading docs now. I am thinking that quick and dirty solution may just be defining a dummy class class ManagerQuerySet(CustomManager, CustomQuerySet): pass and use it as type annotation - objects: ManagerQuerySet = CustomManager.from_queryset(...) # type: ignore. Ugly as hell, but at least good enough for autocomplete to work.

Yeah, possibly good enough. Note that the object is not a subclass of CustomQuerySet, though (at least, not nominally); rather, from_queryset basically copies a lot of CustomQuerySet's attributes into the new subclass of CustomManager. A Protocol that included all the attributes and methods copied by _get_queryset_methods would be more sound, but also much more work.

This is way too dynamic for static typing. Use Any, it shouldn't matter: django-stubs' plugin handles this dynamic type construction correctly.

CustomManager.from_queryset(CustomQuerySet) creates a new subclass of CustomManager at runtime that copies a set of attributes from CustomQuerySet. As such, the "correct" solution would be to define a protocol that enumerates the attributes copied by the private Manager._get_queryset_methods used by from_queryset.
As that is likely a lot of work (and fragile, in that it relies on private implementation details that may change), the broader quick-and-dirty method you propose of pretending that the object is an instance of both CustomManager and CustomQuerySet may be sufficient for your needs.
class ManagerQuerySet(CustomManager, CustomQuerySet):
    pass


class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects: ManagerQuerySet = CustomManager().from_queryset(CustomQuerySet)()

    is_draft = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)

(Really, from_queryset seems to perform a kind of "structural" inheritance, which may not be complete, but good enough to permit the white lie that the new class is a nominal subclass of CustomQuerySet.)

It does not seem to make much sense to place the publish(..) at the manager level, since one might want to publish all sorts of QuerySets.
You typically define this on the QuerySet with:
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def live(self) -> CustomQuerySet['MyModel']:
        return self.filter(is_draft=False)

    def publish(self):
        return self.update(is_draft=False)
and then you inject the CustomQuerySet with:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects: QuerySet['MyModel'] = CustomQuerySet.as_manager()
You can then publish a set of items with the QuerySet, like:
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).publish()

I agree that in this minimal example at first glance it doesn't make much sense - in my project I have much larger Manager, that is also dealing with versioning changes, keeping history of them, soft-deletes, following authorship (each manager method also takes user param) etc. So I have in my queryset only readonly methods (draft, archived, live), while others are manager concern. In this context does it still make sense to keep that all at queryset level?
